# How can Spring Boot Webflux process a little more data when CPU usage is already at 99.9%?

Tags: java, spring-boot, webserver, spring-webflux, http2

I have  implemented a RestFul service using spring boot webflux reactive framework. Server has an endpoint with the GET method and with the resource /home/getData, which simply accepts the request and responds with http2 200 OK. There is no CPU intensive computation such as IO operation or DB access etc. But the CPU utilization of the server application goes up to 99.9%, if the TPS crosses beyond a certain level as given below.

CPU utilization while pumping traffic to the server with two http2 client connection

1. Pushed 1K traffic, CPU consumption was 25%
2. Pushed 10K traffic, CPU computation was 99.9%
3. Pushed 12K traffic, CPU consumption was 99.9%

From above traffic pattern, I could see that the cpu utilization reached 99.9% at 10 tps (i.e. #2), further increasing the traffic rate to 12K tps(i.e. In #3), the server is able to successfully handle extra 2K traffic even though the CPU utilization reached the peak.

How is the server able to process extra 2K traffic in #3 when the cpu utilization is already at 99.9% in #2, Can someone please help me understand?

Comment: Have you looked at the percentiles of the response times ? Maybe at 12K, responses took more time ? And what about memory ? Webflux is designed to manage back-pressure. Having a few thousand requests waiting should not be a problem. But, they might take more time to be answered, and while waiting, they should also consume memory. P.S there have been a video about that by Spring not long ago, you should find it on Spring channel on youtube.

Comment: @amanin Yes, you are right. There is an increase in latency but did not observe an increase in memory.